# What is the proper way to typeset a vector that has a uniform value?

Tags: index-notation

I have an first-rank tensor for acceleration in four dimensions. My first instinct would be to write that out as $A^\alpha$ to show there are four components to the value, but how would you write this if all the components shared the same value? Would you display it as $\boldsymbol{A}$ or just $A$? For example, in just about every textbook, the Geodesic equation is described as:$$0=\Gamma^\alpha_{\mu\nu}U^\mu U^\nu+\frac{dU^\alpha}{d\tau}$$But isn't it more accurate to say:$$0^\alpha=\Gamma^\alpha_{\mu\nu}U^\mu U^\nu+\frac{dU^\alpha}{d\tau}$$So, if the vector contains the same value for each of the components, what is the proper way to typeset it?

Comment: If you like $0^\mu$ or any other constant feel free to use it but it is the first time that I see it. More common is $0$ (there is only one zero vector). Acceptable is
$$
A^\mu=\begin{pmatrix}0\\\vdots\\0\end{pmatrix}
$$ 
(or any other constant). Or you find verbal ways to express that each component $A^\mu$ is that constant. The option $\mathbf{A}$ is pretty bad. Boldface letters are usually used for vectors or tensors not for their components. But then again we live in a free country and you can explain your conventions.

Comment: I am not entirely convinced of what I am writing, but when you write a tensor identity, you could understand it as an equation between scalars which holds true for all values of the free (=not contracted) indexes. In this respect, $A^\mu=0$ could be fine even without interpreting $0$ as the notation for the zero tensor. Even $A^\mu=1$ could be fine, but definitely one should specify with words to avoid misunderstandings.